# Get Standard Deviation and Variance of log 10 data in Excel

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, logarithm, excel

In Excel, my data is between 0.000001 and 0.005 and treated as "logarithmic" so I transformed by log 10 (log10(x)) which are all negative.

The Excel Var.P() and Stdev.p() functions can only return positive values that when combined with antilog using POWER(10, ~) calculates as

- POWER(10, VAR.P(J1:J100)) = 1.7
- POWER(10, STDEV.P(J1:J100)) = 3.1

These are far too large to be used meaningfully for the original data. A value of 0.0001 +/- 3.1 covers many times more than 1 standard deviation.

I am clearly doing something wrong. Can I calculate Var and SD for this logarithmic data?

Comment: exponentiating the variance of the logs doesn't provide a suitable estimate of anything I can think of. What are you doing that for? What was that supposed to tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the variance and the logarithm doesn't commute. I.e.:
$$
Var(X) \ne pow(10, Var(\log_{10}(X)),
$$
because $\log_{10}()$ and $Var()$ don't commute.

So what you can do is:

- either you take the variance/stdev of your original data and then, if you wish, the logarithm thereof, which yields the **logarithm of the variance** ($\log_{10}(Var(X))$), or
- you first take the logarithm, then the variance, which yields **the variance of the logarithmic data** ($Var(\log_{10}(X))$).

Comment: Thank you @frank